# IndexedDB. How to update records as cursor moves

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

In a synchronization method I´m opening a cursor and sending Ajax posts to server. I need at the same time to set the record "flag" to synchronized.

```
var transaction = db.transaction([STORE],IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
transaction.objectStore(STORE).openCursor().onsuccess = function(e){
    var cursor = e.target.result;
    if(cursor){
        if (cursor.value.flag == "0") {

            //sync method                               
            cursor.update(cursor.value.flag = "1")  // not working

        };              
        cursor.continue();
    };
};
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try:

```
cursor.value.flag = "1";
cursor.update(cursor.value);
```

Comment: Of course... cursor.value is the whole object, change the property -> update the object. Thanks.